Use repositoty when use firebase
I am coding application on mvvm model and use firebase authentication, firestore.
I would like to ask how to implement them. because, Firebase auth and firestore functions are all asynchronous.
    fun sendPasswordResetEmail() {
        auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    isSendEmailSuccess.postValue(true)
                } else {
                    isSendEmailSuccess.postValue(false)
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {e ->
                if(e is FirebaseAuthException)
                isSendEmailSuccess.postValue(false)
            }
    }

example, here is the code that implements the forgot password functionality. and i am implementing it in the viewmodel. If code in repository, then how do i deploy it
I tried
    suspend fun sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress: String) : Boolean {
        var result = false
        auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    result = true
                } else {
                    result = false
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {e ->
                result = true

            }.await()
        return result
    }

I tried to code like this in the repository, but the code looks a bit redundant when having to create a result variable and call await(). is there a better way
